Equivalent to UNLOAD PLUS FORMAT STANDARD in IBM HPU 5.1.0 - z/OS
I'm using the IBM HPU with UNLOAD PLUS syntax in some jobs, in z/OS.
Is there any way to reproduce the STANDARD format that UNLOAD PLUS have in HPU?
When I unload some table with HPU syntax I'm not able to reproduce the same output as using HPU with UNLOAD PLUS syntax.
I know that in HPU 5.2.0 is possible to reproduce it with FORMAT UPLUS-STANDARD, but we are still in 5.1.0!
Thank you in advance!
Ricardo
